# Cancel button beside Eclipse Job Status Bar Progress

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, statusbar, jobs

[image: Example UI picture of a eclipse progress bar]

Eclipse jobs can have a progress bar with a stop button on the side. However on the status bar only a small progress bar appears informing the user that a job is ongoing.

Is it possible to put a small stop button next to the progress in the status bar? This will allow the user to stop the job without opening the "Progress" view.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a Job using `setUser(true)` which will display a popup dialog showing the progress with a Cancel button.